# How do you set the date value on Angular Material datepicker with a variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I need to be able to edit the date of an object in an array. When I try to pass the selected object's date into the Material datepicker, it doesn't work. However, it works if you type in a date as a string. [Please see my Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aijjug?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to set an initial value of the form control. Instead, you want to set the value of the form control in the moment you hit the "edit" button.

Updated code:

```
datePickerControl = new FormControl();

editDate(o: any) {
  this.selectedDate = o;
  this.datePickerControl.setValue(o.date1);
}
```

See also the [updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhixtt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That does not work when biding to an actual angular material datepicker object